# Cyclic hierarchy relationship query Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want a query which  will give the below output from a table upon passing  a bind variable. Database is Oracle 11g R2

```
 WITH X AS (SELECT 'A1'col1, 'B1' col2 FROM dual UNION 
      SELECT 'A1'col1, 'B2' col2 FROM dual UNION 
      SELECT 'A2'col1, 'B2' col2 FROM dual UNION
      SELECT 'A2'col1, 'B3' col2 FROM dual UNION 
      SELECT 'A3'col1, 'B3' col2 FROM dual UNION 
      SELECT 'A3'col1, 'B4' col2 FROM dual UNION 
      SELECT 'A2'col1, 'B4' col2 FROM dual UNION 
      SELECT 'A4'col1, 'B1' col2 FROM dual UNION 
      SELECT 'A5'col1, 'B6' col2 FROM dual UNION 
      SELECT 'A6'col1, 'B4' col2 FROM dual UNION
      SELECT 'A7'col1, 'B8' col2 FROM dual )
```

*for Ex bind var. for col1  :p1* = A2

Output will have all rows except 2 rows which are 'A5 -- B6' and 'A7 -- B8'
In other words, on passing the A2 in bind variable I want all the cyclic relationships involving both the columns.
Expected Output :

```
Col1  Col2
-----  ----
A1     B1
A1     B2
A2     B2
A2     B3
A2     B4
A3     B3
A3     B4
A4     B1
A6     B4
```

Comment: Can you give a sample output ?

Comment: @shrek sure.. i will edit

Comment: I can't seem to follow this question at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want all connected rows. So write a recursive query. Start with A2 then find the related rows.

```
with cte(col1, col2) as
(
  select col1, col2 from x
  where 'A2' in (col1, col2)
  union all
  select x.col1, x.col2 
  from x
  join cte on x.col1 in (cte.col1, cte.col2)
           or x.col2 in (cte.col1, cte.col2)
)
cycle col1, col2 set is_cycle to 1 default 0
select distinct col1, col2
from cte
order by col1, col2;
```

Rextester demo: http://rextester.com/BLUOL59045

Comment: Stunning!! WOW, you are genius. I could never ever come up with cycle is cycle clause.I will definitely deep dive in this unexplored chapter.

Comment: The cycle clause actually only prevents from exceptions when the recursion runs into cycles.

Comment: I see, I have to revisit the recursive query too.I believe  Model Clause can also do something similar right? But thank you so much for this Sir!